# Calculate NetworkX Edge Betweenness Centrality with Coordinate Values and Weighted Edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx, graph-theory

I have a NetworkX dataset ordered in such a way that specifies NodeCoordinate-NodeCoordinate-EdgeWeight. An example of the dataset is provided below:

```
(33, 440) (33, 441) 494.416
(33, 440) (33, 439) 494.688
(33, 440) (32, 441) 708.707670939
(33, 440) (32, 440) 501.896
(33, 440) (34, 439) 680.836350052
(33, 440) (34, 441) 681.679221335
(33, 440) (34, 440) 482.684
(33, 440) (32, 439) 709.245072093
(342, 418) (342, 419) 444.088
(342, 418) (341, 417) 628.035272487
(342, 418) (341, 418) 444.088
```

As can be seen in the above example, the coordinate values in parentheses specify the x and y position of a node within the graph. The first node value repeats eight times ("(33, 440)" in this case) because it defines edge values in each cardinal direction and on the diagonal. I am trying to calculate current flow with NetworkX's edge_current_flow_betweenness_centrality() function for this dataset but have been unable to produce a result. Any thoughts on how to create an output? For this analysis I am using Python 27.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When you say "create an output", can you be more specific about what output you want?

Comment: @Joel thanks for commenting. Simply put, I do not know how to properly put this dataset in to NetworkX to have it calculate current flow.

Comment: I should say that I do not know how to put the information in to Python to have NetworkX calculate calculate current flow.